# Telegram API Bot - CallbackQuery response to the touch of a button

Tags: php, api, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

Actually the question is how to get an answer from the user at the click of a button?
What should be changed\rewritten in the code?

```php
$access_token = '...';
$api = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $access_token;
$output = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
$message = $output['message']['text'];
$chat_id = $output['message']['chat']['id'];

if ($output['callback_query'] != null){
    $data = $output['callback_query']['data'];
    $data_id = $output['callback_query']['id'];
    $chat = $output['callback_query']['message']['chat']['id'];
    switch($data){
        case "/123":
           answerCallback($data_id, '123');
           sendMessage($chat, "123", null);
        break;
        case "/plz":
           answerCallback($data_id, 'plz');
           sendMessage($chat, "plz", null);
        break;
     }
   }
elseif ($message != null) {
    switch($message) {
        case '/test':  
        $inline_button1 = array("text"=>"123","callback_data"=>"/123");
        $inline_button2 = array("text"=>"work plz","callback_data"=>'/plz');
        $inline_keyboard = [[$inline_button1,$inline_button2]];
        $keyboard=array("inline_keyboard"=>$inline_keyboard);
        $replyMarkup = json_encode($keyboard); 
         sendMessage($chat_id, "ok", $replyMarkup);
        break;
    }
}

function sendMessage($chat_id, $message, $replyMarkup) {
  file_get_contents($GLOBALS['api'] . '/sendMessage?chat_id=' . $chat_id . '&text=' . urlencode($message) . '&reply_markup=' . $replyMarkup);
}
function answerCallback($id, $text) {
    file_get_contents($GLOBALS['api'] . '/answerCallbackQuery?callback_query_id='.$id.'&text='.$text);
}
```

This code only allows you to get a response from the message `/test`, and does not respond to button presses.
Uses webhook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at your error log. You forgot to provide a value for `$replyMarkup`.

```
PHP Warning: Missing argument 3 for sendMessage()
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Indeed that is the problem.